# Include добавляет не все данные

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

В общем, есть 2 сущности:

```
public class Project
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    public string ZnName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
}

public class Task
{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double? TimePlan { get; set; }
    public int? ItemsPlan { get; set; }
    public float? ImagesPlan { get; set; }
    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
}
```

В конфигурационных файлах я настроил отношения между ними:

```
        builder.HasMany(x => x.Tasks)
            .WithOne(x => x.Project)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.ProjectId);

        builder
            .HasOne(t => t.Project)
            .WithMany(p => p.Tasks)
            .HasForeignKey(t => t.ProjectId);
```

Я знаю, что достаточно настройки в одну сторону, то от безисходности продублировал их в настройку другой сущности, так как думал, что это решит проблему...

EF Core последняя редакция второй версии.

В своем репозитории делаю вот такую штуку:

```
        var result = await context.Projects.Include(p => p.Tasks)
            .AsNoTracking().ToArrayAsync(cancellationToken);
```

И часть проектов остаются с незаполненной коллекцией Task.

Если попробовать взять какой-то один конкретный проблемный проект и заинклудить в обе стороны:

```
        var project = context.Projects.Where(t => t.Id == 3220).Include(x => x.Tasks).ToList();
        var tasks = context.Tasks.Where(t => t.ProjectId == 3220).Include(x=>x.Project).ToList();
```

То все работает...

Что за ерунда такая?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем, ошибка была глупой и очень не примечательной...

При биндингах одной из этих сущностей забыли, что она имеет составной PK и указали, как PK только ID. Из-за этого его так штормило при выборках...

Самое интересное, что EF молча считывал данные из таблицы и ему было пофигу на то, что поле отмеченное, как PK в биндингах имело дубли...

Comment: вы можете отметить ваш ответ верным, для этого нажмите на...  (этот комментарий будет удалён)

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего ошибка в настройке контекста. Других не нашел.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Project>(entity =>
{
   // Тут нет ключа
    entity.HasMany(x => x.Tasks)
            .WithOne(x => x.Project);
});

modelBuilder.Entity<Task>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasOne(t => t.Project)
          .WithMany(p => p.Tasks)
          .HasForeignKey(t => t.ProjectId);
});
```

Comment: Если бы косяк был в контексте, тогда бы вообще ничего, наверное не грузилось...=(

Comment: По опыту ошибки в конфигурации контекста могут вести к неправильной загрузке/добавлению/удалению данных. Тут явная ошибка в задании внешнего ключа, так как этот ключ может быть только у одной из таблиц.
Также я бы обратил внимание на virtual и его необходимость в классе Project и Task(но вроде влиять не должно)

Comment: Хотя есть еще вариант, что таких данных в БД просто нет.

Comment: Данные я сам лично првоерил и они есть. Ну в первой записи указывается FK опять же из Task, а не из Project, что не должно не на что влиять...

Comment: Есть тогда еще пару предложений как проверить. Разделите запрос на

var resultQuery = сontext.Projects.Include(p => p.Tasks);
var result = await resultQuery.AsNoTracking().ToArrayAsync(cancellationToken);

Тут можно пробрекпоинтить и посмотреть, что в Query и что в result.
И попробуйе заменить .ToArrayAsync(cancellationToken); на ToListAsync() - у нас как-то AsEnumerable в системные логи не попадал из-за баги в ef